# Connecting client and server side typescript projects

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, gulp, parcel

I have one root project which contains both my server and client side apps with roughly the following structure:

```
-- server
  -- node_modules
  -- index.ts
  -- package.json
  -- ...
-- client
  -- node_modules
  -- index.ts
  -- package.json
  -- html/
  -- css/
  -- ...
```

I am looking for the best way to compile all of this and make the client side static files reachable for the server. I tried this by setting the `outDir` to `../build` for the `server` project and setting it to `../build/static` for the `client` project. This did unfortunately not work because `tsc` does not work well with files outside the root folder of the project (e.g. node modules can't be called from the build, correct me if I'm wrong!).
Also, it'd be really nice if I could listen for changes in the typescript file and auto-build that file when such a change is detected.

I looked into options like gulp, Webpack and parcel, but I am not sure what the best and most simple solution is.

One way I got it to work was using one project for the `server` and `client`. The following structure:

```
-- node_modules
-- package.json
-- index.ts
-- server/
-- static/
--   html/
-- ...
```

but this way, there is only one `node_modules` folder and one `package.json` file for both the client and server side, which might not be the best way (again, correct me if I am wrong!).

Answer (score -1):

[crisp-react](https://github.com/winwiz1/crisp-react) has the server and client projects.

Similarities with your setup:
 - Projects are located in `server/` and `client/` directories
 - Each project has its own `package.json` and `node_modules/`
 - Uses Typescript
 - The client side static files are reachable for the server
 - Auto build. There are usage scenarious when the client is automatically rebuilt when source code changes. That is called Live Reloading. The same applies to the server code, it gets rebuilt automatically as you type the source code changes.

What's different:
 - No `css/` directory as CSS for each client component is in the component's .tsx file
 - No `html/` directory because .html files are auto-generated.

Having one single `package.json` and `tsconfig.json` doesn't sound like a great idea because dependencies and settings are rather different.